# Override a specific command button background-color in MVVM using a Shared Resource XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, button, mvvm

How can I change the back-ground color of a specific button without making a new set of styles in the SharedResources.xaml?

**Button Picture**

In this picture below, it shows three buttons using the same styles from the SharedResource.xaml. My goal is to make only the second button change it's color from "WhiteSmoke" to "Purple/Color of my choice".

[Button Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U7rx.png)

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

These buttons are styled in the **SharedResources.xaml**.

```
        protected override void CreateCommands()
    {
        this.Commands.Add(new CommandViewModel("First Button", new DelegateCommand(p => this.BtnOne())));

        this.Commands.Add(new CommandViewModel("Second Button", new DelegateCommand(p => this.BtnTwo())));

        this.Commands.Add(new CommandViewModel("Third Button", new DelegateCommand(p => this.BtnThree())));
    }
```

**SharedResources.saml**

The Background color is "WhiteSmoke". This is the color that I want to override just for that **Second Button** (or any specific button) without the need of creating another set of styles in the SharedResources.xaml.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:System">

<!-- Navigation Style for Buttons -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="CommandsTemplate">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding Path=Command}" Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Width="180" Height="40" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="20" FontStyle="Oblique" Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="8,8,0,0">
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

The buttons are bound in the "HeaderedContentControl's" "Content" and the **Styles** of the buttons are bounded in the "ContentTemplate".

```
<Window x:Class="System.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:System"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Height="550" Width="1080">

<!-- Connect this xaml to SharedResources -->
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="SharedResources.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="4" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Height="60">
        <HeaderedContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Commands}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CommandsTemplate}" />
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="2">
        <HeaderedContentControl Content="{Binding Path=ViewModels}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: First, let your `CommandViewModel` have a property (bool, perhaps) that indicates whether a command is "special" (like the second command) or not. You could then use a [DataTrigger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=netframework-4.7.2) to change the background color based on the value of that property. (Alternatively, you could also use the DisplayName property for the `DataTrigger`, but this is error-prone if you succumb to the desire to change the display name of your buttons and forget to change the DataTriggers accordingly, or use localized names)

Comment: I think it'd be more flexible to expose a brush from the commandviewmodel and bind that in the template. Give the property a default value of Brushes.WhiteSmoke. Then you don't set it at all for most commands and you can set it purple, yellow or whatever you like for others.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the BasedOn attribute to inherit either an exist resource style or the default one:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <!-- Default button style is blue text on a white background -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<!-- Button with blue text on a yellow background -->
<Button Content="Hello World" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```